# I am getting com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0030E

Tags: java, ejb, jndi

I am executing a enterprise application where the front end is developed n swings and back end in ejb.
when i run the application it was not getting started and throwing below error.

"com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/ejb/LoggingManager reference.  The exception message was: The EJB reference in the rtccWeb.war module of the rtcc application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: CNTR4012E: The zom.viveo.rtcc.ide.server.busobjects.LoggingManagerHome remote interface for the LoggingManager enterprise bean in the services.jar module in the rtcc application could not be obtained for injection because remote interfaces are not supported by any of the features configured in the server.xml file. 
\
I have entry in web.xml as below

ejb/LoggingManager         Session            com.viveo.rtcc.ide.server.busobjects.LoggingManagerHome            com.viveo.rtcc.ide.server.busobjects.LoggingManager            services.jar#LoggingManager</ejb-link -->         
java:global/rtcc/services/LoggingManager!com.viveo.rtcc.ide.server.busobjects.LoggingManager

Please help...

Comment: typo errr the entry in web.xml as below

Comment: typo error. entryin web.xml is below   <ejb-ref id="EjbRef_1">
  <description></description>
  <ejb-ref-name>ejb/LoggingManager</ejb-ref-name>
  <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
  <home>com.viveo.rtcc.ide.server.busobjects.LoggingManagerHome</home>
  <remote>com.viveo.rtcc.ide.server.busobjects.LoggingManager</remote>
  <!-- ejb-link>services.jar#LoggingManager</ejb-link -->
  <ejb-link>java:global/rtcc/services/LoggingManager!com.viveo.rtcc.ide.server.busobjects.LoggingManager</ejb-link>
 </ejb-ref>